# Using Vulkan unique handle in struct leads to "implicitly deleted" error

Tags: c++, gpu, unique-ptr, vulkan

I have this in my code:

```
struct Buffer
        {
            vk::UniqueBuffer buffer;
            vk::UniqueDeviceMemory memory;
            unsigned int top{0};
        };

        struct Image
        {
            vk::UniqueImage textureImage;
            vk::UniqueDeviceMemory textureImageMemory;
        };

        struct Texture
        {
            Image image;
            vk::UniqueImageView imageView;
            vk::UniqueSampler sampler;
        };

        struct SwapChainFrame
        {
            vk::Image image;
            vk::UniqueImageView imageView;
            vk::UniqueFramebuffer frameBuffer;
            vk::UniqueCommandBuffer commandBuffer;
            Buffer uniformVpMatrix;
            vk::UniqueDescriptorSet descriptorSet;
        };
```

Storing unique handles in Vulkan worked well till I added the Image and Texture ones. Now I'm getting this:

```
   In file included from .../gpuVulkan.h:50:16: note: ‘GpuVulkan::Texture::Texture(const GpuVulkan::Texture&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
             struct Texture
                    ^~~~~~~
    .../gpuVulkan.h:50:16: error: use of deleted function ‘GpuVulkan::Image::Image(const GpuVulkan::Image&)’
    .../gpuVulkan.h:44:16: note: ‘GpuVulkan::Image::Image(const GpuVulkan::Image&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
             struct Image
                    ^~~~~
    .../gpuVulkan.h:44:16: error: use of deleted function ‘vk::UniqueHandle<Type, Dispatch>::UniqueHandle(const vk::UniqueHandle<Type, Dispatch>&) [with Type = vk::Image; Dispatch = vk::DispatchLoaderStatic]’
    In file included from .../gpuVulkan.h:1,
                     from .../src/gpuVulkan.cpp:5:
    /usr/include/vulkan/vulkan.hpp:392:5: note: declared here
         UniqueHandle( UniqueHandle const& ) = delete;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from ...gpuVulkan.cpp:5:
    .../gpuVulkan.h:44:16: error: use of deleted function ‘vk::UniqueHandle<Type, Dispatch>::UniqueHandle(const vk::UniqueHandle<Type, Dispatch>&) [with Type = vk::DeviceMemory; Dispatch = vk::DispatchLoaderStatic]’
             struct Image
```

Any ideas what's wrong? The Buffer and SwapChainFrame works well. Seems like a similar issue was reported [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/issues/233) but I'm not sure if this is the same problem. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Your entire resource model seems kinda broken. Multiple textures ought to be able to use the same sampler or the same image, but they can't under your model. Multiple buffers (and textures for that matter) ought to be able to use the same piece of device memory, but they can't in your model.

Comment: @NicolBolas I actually use only one huge buffer for scene data. About textures you might be right, I just got to this part so still trying to figure out the best way to use multiple textures. I got inspired by Kyle Halladay's article about arrays of textures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Image` class doesn't have a copy constructor (because `vk::UniqueImage` doesn't have a copy constructor).  That means `Texture` doesn't have a copy constructor either.

The other classes don't have a copy constructor either, but that's OK unless you try to copy them.  (In this case, from the comments, by creating a `std::vector<Texture>`.)

Comment: Oh so the UniqueImage is different from the other handles?

Comment: @Hitokage: None of the `Unique*` handles has a copy constructor. That's why they're "unique".

Comment: @Hitokage: Because you didn't try to copy them. You must have put `Texture` in a place that required a copy constructor.

Comment: @NicolBolas Aaah it makes sense! Yea I used the Texture in vector. Sorry it's clear now. I thought that the definition was the problem, not the usage. Such a silly mistake sorry for even asking and thanks for help.

Comment: @Hitokage Don't worry about it.  We've all made mistakes that are *at least* as stupid as that one.  It goes with the territory.